# Как быстро обработать 15000000 строк csv файла, для вставки в бд

Tags: python, php, c#, mysql

Есть файлик csv, на 15000000 которые нужно переместить в таблицу в бд MySQL. Файл обновляется каждые 30 минут. Есть вариант использовать временною метку только на обновления даных внутри файла. Как правильно сделать? Технология неважна.

В файле будет код товара, цена, наличие.
Файл обновляться каждый час, его выгружаем.
Возможно там будет метка временных, что-бы актуальным только брать. Но не факт.
Но в дальнейшем это будет или обновление или вставка нового товара.

Comment: Каков характер обновления? Полностью новый файл? Дополняются строки в конце? Что-то ещё? Добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это пробовали? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: Можно загрузить через pandas.
На подобии
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816651/how-do-i-load-a-csv-into-mysql-using-pandas

Comment: C# - поможет библиотека CsvHelper

Comment: Сомнительно, что в большинстве случаев  за час в файле с информацией о товарах появится много изменений. Я бы начал с diff-а, между текущей и предыдущей версиями файла, а потом внес изменения в базу. Но более правильным решением, было бы перепроектирование системы так, чтобы поставщик этого файла сам накапливал только изменения и отсылал их

Comment: Хорошо, сделал вставку.
Дальше мне нужно скачивать єтот файл каждие 60 минут и обновлять дание текущие в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно быстрым вариантом будет использовать `LOAD DATA INFILE` напрямую в бд без необходимости перебора данных программой.